# MS unit testing azure table storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, azure

I have been doing quite some time on Azure project and so far it’s going pretty good. Learned a lot!

Now I need to integrate a unit tester almost half way to my project (which doesn’t seem easy anymore?)

In short, I use Azure table storage to store my data for an asp.net mvc3 project (VS2010). And currently I need to test the basic CRUD ActionResults .
Can I use the free MS unit testers?
Is there any hint or clue how to so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll typically do in such a scenario is first create an interface, like ITableStorage and then create an implementation (AzureTableStorage for example) that wraps around the Azure specific stuff.

This makes it easy to replace the actual implementation with a mock/stub during your unit tests. You can take a look at the Windows Azure Helpers for an example of such an interface and a wrapper implementation: [Windows Azure Helpers](http://azuretoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/46c9fb9ff82a#Source/AzureToolkit/AzureTableBase.cs).

This is a good blog post about unit testing and Windows Azure: http://blogs.southworks.net/fboerr/2010/07/23/windows-azure-storage-tdd-and-mocks/

And to answer your question, yes you can use this with MSTest.

Comment: FYI, that blog has moved to http://southworks.com/blog/2010/07/23/windows-azure-storage-tdd-and-mocks/.